# Zend Java Bridge can't call interface methods?

Tags: java, php, jms, tibco, zend-server

While trying to implement Tibco JMS messaging in PHP via Zend Java Bridge I'm doing a standard procedure like:

```
$factory = java('com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory', $srv);
$connection = $factory->createConnection($usr, $pwd);

$t = new java('javax.jms.Session');
$session = $connection->createSession(false, $t->AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

$destination = $session->createQueue($qName);
```

And on the last line of this fragment I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createQueue
```

The **createQueue** method is a part of the **Session** interface that is implemented by the class of my $session object (supposed to be in that way). When I do the same in pure Java, everything works just fine, so I suspect Zend Java Bridge lacking functionality of calling interface methods. Has anyone dealt with a similar problem before, and are there any workarounds (except implementing the whole logic in Java and calling it from PHP)?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I kind of have a similar issue and no luck getting it to work.

Comment: @KareyPowell I got this working by writing my own simple wrapper class in Java which handles all that connection/session/message stuff and provides basic public methods. As I remember, Zend Java Bridge has some issues with calling non-trivial method signatures (like interface implementation methods, or something like that -- can't remember now). So try to use bare public methods and wrap all inheritance stuff into your own wrapper class.